# Actuating a pneumatic solenoid manifold with Arduino

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I need to programmatically actuate 5 pneumatic solenoids. Would it be feasible to do this by coupling a sufficient number of driver boards like one would use with stepper motors (i.e EasyDriver) to something like an Arduino Mega 2560 R3?

The solenoids I'm considering are 12vdc 3w.

Comment: What are the electrical specs (voltage and current requirements) of the solenoids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a ULN2001 a shot: it's a pretty good jellybean driver. You can put the channels in parallel to drive higher currents (each is 0.5A).

http://datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/U/L/N/2/ULN2001.shtml

The also have freewheeling diodes built-in so you don't have to worry about driving inductive loads like solenoid or stepper coils.